# fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists

Tags: git, github

I am very new to Git and GitHub. While learning it from one of the YouTube videos I encountered the following message

> fatal: 'orgin' does not appear to be a git repository fatal: Could not
> read from remote repository Please make sure you have the correct
> access rights and the repository exists.

I know that many people have asked similar question but looking at their replies I cannot figure out what to do next.

I've run the following commands in order:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/shrey1605/GitLearnRepo.git
git remote -v
git push -u origin master
git checkout dev
git commit -am "new change in dev"
```

Comment: The error message shows "orgin" (typo) but your commands have the correct "origin". It's not clear what the problem is now.

Answer (score 2):

It appears as though **origin** is misspelled:

```
fatal: 'orgin' does not appear ...
```

This will cause the error every time.  (It’s bitten me a few times too)